# Git 'pack-objects died of signal 13' when pushing to origin

Tags: git, github, version-control, version

Whenever I work on a branch other than master and try to push to that branch I get this error:

```
User-MacBook-Pro:htdocs user$ git push origin quotes
Counting objects: 2494, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2246/2246), done.
Write failed: Broken pipe9/2455)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github..com:theuser/therepo.git'
```

All I did to achieve this was an add, then a commit and a push. I've tried packaging the files inside but they aren't much, 30 mbs or so. I've also tried to send via SSH and HTTP but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Comment: After changing the buffer time I now get this:                                                             error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: For reference I'm trying to push protractor and karma modules

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar error when trying to push to a repository I didn't have permissions to write to.
As in I could read the repo through SSH, but permissions on repo were set up so I couldn't write.

What helped was (on remote server):

```
cd /repo/dir
chown +R owner:git_group
chmod 770 .
```

Then add user to `git_group` group :)

Answer (score 0):

Mine did the same thing and this was on gitlab.com
After increasing the buffer size;
The solution that worked was using "git pack"

and after that I ran the push command again and it worked:

Documentation is available here [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/troubleshooting_git.html)